# CRUD Screen using N-Tier Architecture

Tags: asp.net, n-tier-architecture

net page with lot of controls and validations. I need to allow users to Save the application into the database.

I have a Master table Called Customer and 5 different child tables with Customer_ID being foreign key.

Once the user hits save I need to insert a record into customer table and then insert records into relevent child tables with the just created customer_ID.

Can you guys suggest me a good example of the above mentioned scenario that would be of great help.

I created a model for Customer and all the child tables. But I really don;t know how to proceed from here.

I am using VB.net and ASP.net 2.0 and oracle 8g. We cannot use the ASP.net 3.5 or MVC 1.0.

Please help

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET website has a wealth of examples.

http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would definitely do is make sure you use transactions to ensure data integrity. The [transactions could be within a stored procedure](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513004758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080305-1.shtml) or using [the .NET transaction classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx). Either way, you want to make sure that if there is an exception when saving your data that the database is rolled back to a consistent state.